# Applying hover effect on multiple li

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following `ul` with 5 `li`.

Now is there a way i can apply **different hover effects to each li** without giving `id` to each `li`

```
<ul class="navigate">
       <li>One</li>
       <li>two</li>
       <li>Three</li>
       <li>Four</li>
       <li>Five</li>
 </ul>
```

Or is it necessary for me to give `ID/Class` to each li???

Comment: @ArunPJohny If i do above it will have same hover effect for all right???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the :nth-child() selector to apply different hover effects to each li elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

**Example**

```
ul.navigate li:hover:nth-child(1) {
   background: black;
}

ul.navigate li:hover:nth-child(2) {
   background: red;
}
```

and so on...

Comment: THanks a lot.Workedperfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can even just use css only:

```
li:nth-child(1){color: 'red';}
li:nth-child(2){color: 'blue';}
li:nth-child(3):hover{color: 'red';}

/*and like so*/
```

Before using nth-child selector please check this for browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

But if you give them unique id would be the best practice that works on older browsers too.

Answer (score 1):

jquery is not neccessary for this.
how about :nth.child property in css?

[CSSTricks - :nth-child(n)](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

[W3C - :nth-child(n)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

But if you really want to use jQuery look at this

[jQuery - :nth-child(n)](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery

```
$('.navigate li').eq(x).css(...); // with x from 0 to 4
```

or

```
$('.navigate li').eq(x).hover(function(){},function(){});
```